# Android cordova chromeview : Not implemented reached in virtual quota::SpecialStoragePolicy

Tags: android, cordova, chromium

I'm working on a phonegap project which contains a canvas overlayed with kinetic.js, which allows a user to pinch zoom and pan around an image, then draw annotations on it. it works spliendidly in a browser and on windows and apple tablets, but of course android is a good bit slower.

as a solution, i've released the app using https://github.com/thedracle/cordova-android-chromeview. after switching my main java class to use ChromeView as the webview, i'm getting this error on startup:

```
12-03 13:21:09.083: E/chromium(13917): [ERROR:aw_browser_context.cc(191)] Not implemented reached in virtual quota::SpecialStoragePolicy* android_webview::AwBrowserContext::GetSpecialStoragePolicy()
```

after debugging through the codebase, it looks like the error is triggering here:

```
private void setNativeContentsClientBridge(int nativeContentsClientBridge) {
    mNativeContentsClientBridge = nativeContentsClientBridge;
}
```

(AwContentsClientBridge.java line 36).

i'm trying to find out what the nativeContentsClientBridge int is. My value is 1611312352 but i haven't a notion of what that represents.

my gut feel is that the chromium browser is missing an implementation for accessing localstorage. i found this bug:

https://github.com/pwnall/chromeview/issues/27

where someone is experiencing the same thing, but there is no solution.

for assistance, this is my main activity class:

```
package com.companion;

import org.apache.cordova.Config;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity;

import us.costan.chrome.ChromeSettings;
import us.costan.chrome.ChromeView;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class CompanionApp extends CordovaActivity
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        ChromeView chromeView = new ChromeView(CompanionApp.this);

        ChromeSettings settings = chromeView.getSettings(); 
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
        settings.setDatabaseEnabled(true); 
        settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        setContentView(chromeView);
        super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help,
Margaret

Comment: okdokies, after going around on a maaaassive wild goose chase, it turns out that the reason my app isn't running is that i was missing the line:

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

at the start of my onCreate function. the specialstoragepolicy doesn't seem to actually affect anything. hope this helps someone!

Margaret

Comment: hi, i was also missing this line: ChromeView.initialize(this); which happens after the super.create call and before trying to instantiate the ChromeView instance. The docco on the chromeview project is light, but I must say it has given an incredible boost to performance. It has gone from totally unusable, to a pretty slick app. Margaret

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it's normal, but it seems that a method's not implemented in Chromium base code : https://github.com/01org/pa-chromium/blob/master/android_webview/browser/aw_browser_context.cc

Here's that particular method:

```
quota::SpecialStoragePolicy* AwBrowserContext::GetSpecialStoragePolicy() {
  // TODO(boliu): Implement this so we are not relying on default behavior.
  NOTIMPLEMENTED();
  return NULL;
}
```

I hope it helps :)